# sqlite3 query to perform a operation twice

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working with sqlite3 and I've created a view named collabs having columns id_1, id_2, count, score.

What I want is to extract data from above view as two rows for one row like if in database data is stored as `(11, 44, 3, 55.8)`
I want to perform a query that would return (id, count, average)
`(11, 3, 55.8)`
`(4, 3, 55.8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with a union all operation:

```
select id_1 as id, count, score as average from collabs
union all
select id_2 as id, count, score as average from collabs
```

But it is not clear why you called the third column 'average', what is it the average of?